# Has the relative sign in the Dirac equation any meaning?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, conventions, fermions, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices

I know there are many questions about this topic and also various answers, but it's never stated explicitly, why there is a certain sign before the mass term in the Dirac Lagrangian. I'm also confused, since the text I'm following, it is stated without proof that

> The relative sign between the two Lorentz-Scalars can be deduced, by
>   implying that the equation of motion must satisfy the Klein-Gordon-Equation for every
>   components.

But when I tried to get to this result by keeping the $\pm$ explicitly through all calculations, I saw that it drops out anyways

$$\mathcal{L} = i\bar{\Psi}(\partial_\mu \gamma^\mu \pm m)\Psi$$

Euler-Lagrange equation yields

$$\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\bar{\Psi}} - \partial_\mu\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial\bar{\Psi})} = (i\partial_\mu\gamma^\mu \pm m)\Psi = 0. $$

Multiplying the hermitian conjugate of the operator from the left

$$
\begin{align}
0 &= (-i\partial_\nu\gamma^\nu \pm m)(i\partial_\mu\gamma^\mu \pm m)\Psi \\
&=(\partial_\mu\gamma^\mu\partial_\nu\gamma^\nu \pm im\partial_\mu\gamma^\mu\mp im\partial_\nu\gamma^\nu+m^2)\Psi \\
&= (\frac{1}{2} \left[\partial_\mu\gamma^\mu\partial_\nu\gamma^\nu + \partial_\mu\gamma^\mu\partial_\nu\gamma^\nu\right] + m^2)\Psi \\
&= (\frac{1}{2}\{\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu\}\partial_\mu\partial_\nu + m^2)\Psi \\
&= (\partial_\mu\partial^\mu + m^2)\Psi = 0,
\end{align}$$

where the identity matrix has been suppressed. So this seems indeed to be the Klein-Gordon-Equation for each component of the spinor, but the $\pm$ drops out in the beginning.

> Hence, my question does it matter which sign we choose (at the level
>   of the Lagrangian), and is there a deeper reason of why to choose one
>   or the other?

Comment: Your Lagrangian density seems to have the i at the wrong place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say, $\Psi$ is a solution of Dirac equation, that is, $$(i\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}-m)\Psi=0.$$

Multiplying by $\gamma^5$ and using $\gamma^5\gamma^{\mu}=-\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^5$,
$$(i\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}+m)\gamma^5\Psi=0.$$
Thus, $\gamma^5\Psi$ is also a solution with mass $-m$. The two solutions correspond to the two factors of $E^2=p^2+m^2$. Since Dirac equation is linear, the linear combinations of its solutions: $\psi_L=\frac{1}{2}(1-\gamma^5)\Psi$ and $\psi_R=\frac{1}{2}(1+\gamma^5)\Psi$, will also be solutions.

All this basically means that Dirac equation describes two solutions and depending upon the choice of basis (for $\gamma$-matrices) these solutions could be interpreted as particle and anti-particle (in Dirac basis) or two-component left- and right- handed Weyl spinors (in chiral basis). These components separately are solutions to the Klein-Gordon equation.

EDIT: Notice that in the last expression in the question, there is no $\gamma$-matrix, so each component satisfies the K-G equation individually. As per the disappearance of the $\pm$ sign, I think it has to do with the fact that EOM for both $\Psi$ and $\bar{\Psi}$ (Dirac equation and its adjoint, respectively) can be obtained from the same Lagrangian by varying it w.r.t. to $\bar{\Psi}$ and $\Psi$, respectively. So, in that sense, it doesn't matter which one you begin with (the Dirac Lagrangian with the minus sign or its adjoint with the plus sign). They carry the same information; they're just adjoint of each other!

For detailed explanation, [go here](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath654/kmath654.htm).

A similar thread is [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/202419/is-the-dirac-equation-equivalent-to-the-klein-gordon-equation-for-its-left-hande).

Comment: Oke so changing the sign in the Lagrangian corresponds to a redefinition of what is a right or left handed Weyl-spinor? Hence, it would not be possible to determine the sign of the Lagrangian mass term, just by stating that the EOM have to fulfill the Klein-Gordon equation?

Comment: @PatrickAmrein see the EDITed answer above. I hope this completes the discussion.

Answer (score 2):

Change of the sign at the mass in the Dirac equation is equivalent to replacing $\gamma^\mu$ with $-\gamma^\mu$, but matrices $-\gamma^\mu$ have the same anti-commutation relations as $\gamma^\mu$, so you get an equivalent equation, if I am not mistaken. Specific solutions may have a different form, but the physics seems to be the same.